# How to translate multi files by Google translation API?

Tags: google-translation-api

I'd like to translate multi .pptx files. I'm trying to use [Google translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents#translate_documents_batch)

My request json file is below.

```
{
    "source_language_code": "ja",
    "target_language_codes": ["en"],
    "input_configs": {
        "gcsSource": {
            "inputUri": "gs://project_name/1.pptx"
        },
        "gcsSource": {
            "inputUri": "gs://project_name/2.pptx"
        }
    },
    "output_config": {
        "gcsDestination": {
            "outputUriPrefix": "gs://project_name/ja-en/"
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error, when I request translation API.

```
"description": "Invalid value at 'input_configs' (oneof), oneof field 'source' is already set. Cannot set 'gcsSource'"
```

Then I changed second `gcsSource` to `gcsSource1`

```
{
    "source_language_code": "ja",
    "target_language_codes": ["en"],
    "input_configs": {
        "gcsSource": {
            "inputUri": "gs://project_name/1.pptx"
        },
        "gcsSource1": {
            "inputUri": "gs://project_name/2.pptx"
        }
    },
    "output_config": {
        "gcsDestination": {
            "outputUriPrefix": "gs://project_name/ja-en/"
        }
    }
}
```

The result was below.

```
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"gcsSource1\" at 'input_configs': Cannot find field."
```

`gcsSource1` was used 2 times in [the document](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents#translate_documents_batch)

[image]

How should I chagne request json file, for translate multi files by translation API?

Endpoint is this. `"https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/project_name/locations/us-central1:batchTranslateDocument"`

---

**Note**

Single file translation works fine.

```
{
    "source_language_code": "ja",
    "target_language_codes": ["en"],
    "input_configs": {
        "gcsSource": {
            "inputUri": "gs://project_name/1.pptx"
        },
    },
    "output_config": {
        "gcsDestination": {
            "outputUriPrefix": "gs://project_name/ja-en/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the correct API endpoint? The endpoint for batch requests is different as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents#translate_documents_batch).

Comment: Yes. My endpoint is batch request. "https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/project_name/locations/us-central1:batchTranslateDocument"

Comment: You are using curly braces within input_configs, since it has multiple values in your case, it will be a square bracket as it is an array.

Comment: Hi @Nori, I am glad it worked, I was planning to post the same as answer and if you could accept/upvote it.

Comment: Yes! it's OK! I'll delete my answer after your post.

Comment: Hi, I posted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the curly braces used within `input_configs`. Since you want to use multiple elements, input_configs should be an array. So you should switch the curly braces with square braces as follows:

```
"input_configs": [
    {
      "gcsSource": {
        "inputUri": "gs://bucket_name/1.pptx"
      }
    },
    {
      "gcsSource": {
        "inputUri": "gs://bucket_name/2.pptx"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Also, you cannot change the names of json keys, as the structure of request.json which will be passed to the endpoint should be as mentioned in the documentation. This is the reason that when you change the key to `“gcsSource1”`, it gives you an error with “Cannot find field”.